# LLDB — evaluate and continue

Tags: lldb

XCode has functionality to set breakpoint, then run lldb command and *“Automatically continue after evaluating”*.

How to setup same functionality via `--source` ? Found `--command` quote in the manual, but no examples and no reference in sub-command help

`By default, the breakpoint command add command takes lldb command line commands. You can also specify this explicitly by passing the "--command" option.`

```
Syntax: command <sub-command> [<sub-command-options>] <breakpoint-id>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking about auto-continue with lldb?

I used the `modify` command to add auto-continue..

```
(lldb) b CCCryptorCreate
Breakpoint 1: where = libcommonCrypto.dylib`CCCryptorCreate, address = 0x000000011047e1b7

(lldb) breakpoint modify --auto-continue true 1
(lldb) br list
Current breakpoints:
1: name = 'CCCryptorCreate', locations = 1, resolved = 1, hit count = 0 Options: enabled auto-continue 
  1.1: where = libcommonCrypto.dylib`CCCryptorCreate, address = 0x000000011047e1b7, resolved, hit count = 0
```

then to add some commands I used..

```
(lldb) breakpoint command add -s python 1
Enter your Python command(s). Type 'DONE' to end.
    print "Hit this breakpoint!"
    DONE
```

The help has some good examples `(lldb) help breakpoint command add`

Comment: thank you, `--auto-continue true`, to avoid ambiguity with `breakpoint command add 1` where `1` is `<breakpoint-id>`. Per help: `<boolean> -- A Boolean value: 'true' or 'false'`

Comment: @IsaakOsipovichDunayevsky I was having problems with the `command add` line.  When I specified a language, it worked perfectly.  Thought you might like to know! :o)

Comment: you might find helping info on lldb in this 2018 video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/412/

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely clear what you are asking.

But if you want to put commands in a text file somewhere which will add set a breakpoint and add commands to it you want something like:

```
> cat /tmp/cmds.lldb
break set -F main
break command add
frame var
continue
DONE
> lldb -s /tmp/cmds.lldb myBinary
```

Or if you want to do this in Xcode, just use:

```
(lldb) command source /tmp/cmds.lldb
```

once you are in the Xcode debugging session.

This relies on one trick, the "breakpoint command add" command operates on the last breakpoint set, which was why I didn't have to specify the breakpoint number.

Comment: I want to set breakpoint at specific line. Breakpoints may resolve to one location, `continue` will ignore following logical breakpoints for one location

Answer (score 0):

`help breakpoint command add` reveals it is called `--one-liner`, `--command` must be a typo?

```
-o <one-line-command> ( --one-liner <one-line-command> )
     Specify a one-line breakpoint command inline.
```

Question is actual, how to automatically `continue` when `--source` is used

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you are asking.  Do you want to put a command that auto-continues in a text file somewhere which makes the breakpoint and adds commands to it, and then do: